# how to determine whether each border side of a string rectangle contains at least one specified character?

Tags: java

Lets say there is a string that represents a rectangle, and this rectangle only contains two types of chars that are '.' and 'x':

```
String layout = "..x.\nx..x\n.x.."
System.out.println(layout) ->     ..x.
                                  x..x
                                  .xx.
```

how can I determine whether each border side of the rectangle has at least one 'x'?(use a boolean method) For example,

```
//this one is not illegal, because its left side border does not have an 'x' 
 ..x.
 ..xx
 .xx.
```

I have put this rectangle in a string[][], which means I have a coordinate for each char in this rectangle. My idea is using four for-loops to check four sides, but it is kind of redundant. Can anyone give a better idea? Thanks

Comment: How exactly does that string represent a rectangle?

Comment: @user4593157 : Would you explain your Output? Which String is Valid for your Output?

Comment: @HardyRocks lets say I have a method: public boolean onBorder(String layout), layout is a parameter, and I need to determine if each side of this layout contains at least one'x'

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well, what you want to do than, You can try this.
You have any `String[][]` which holds random Strings and each String must have at least `x` in it.

```
 str[0] X . . .
 str[1] . X . .
 str[2] . . X .
 str[3] . . . X
```

now you need to check `str[i] > isContainLatterX()` which returns `boolean` if there is presence of `X`.
For Example :

```
public boolean isContainLatterX(String str){
    if(str.contains("X"))
          return true;
    else
          return false;
}
```

Now, need an another Method which returns the `Index` of occurrence of latter `X` say `indexOfLatterX(String str)`

```
public int indexOfLatterX(String str){
    return str.indexOf("X");
}
```

Just call both these Methods in Your Loop, and check Latter X is Exists or not, if Not than Generate Error, and skip remaining Progress. if Exists than Check its Index with previous Strings, if there is Matching Index founds than Generate Error and Skip remaining Progress.

Comment: better if  we check firstIndexOf() and lastIndexOf() methods inside indexOfLatterX() and check whether the finding letter is in a border area.

Comment: @Jude Niroshan : yes we can call any of these three methods, if there is only a Single character presence.

Answer (score 0):

Can we try, just getting the co-ordinates in form of [x][y],
 and check that x and y values exist in range of length... 
Missing values gives the empty lines

```
 ..x.
 .x..
 ...x
 x...
```

The [x][y] list will be (0,2),(1,1),(2,3),(3,0) and must be in range {0,3}

We check that x and y has values `(0-3)` available. If any value is missing, then the corresponding row or column, don't have an `x`

Since it represents the border side, you can check for **`(x,y)`** in range **`{0,length-1}`**

Comment: what if there are a lot of  'x' in the rectangle? Wouldn't it be a little bit redundant to find out every 'x' 's coordinate first?

Comment: @user4593157 If you find an x in row wise, it could be eliminated for pre-existing value of same x and y stands for column wise..